# What is the purpose of the Look Up button on a Logitecth MX Keys Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, logitech

Everything is in the title. I wonder if anyone knows how to use the Look Up button on a Logitech Mx Keys. I saw in Logitect Options that it does a look up but what does that mean exactly? Any idea?
I'm talking about the button surrounded by red in this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Mac OS, you can highlight a word and press the `Look Up` button to see the definition pop up in Chrome. I believe this is the same action as selecting a word, right clicking it, then pressing on the `Look Up "...."` option.

You can also press the `fn` key with the `Look Up` button to toggle scroll lock.

Comment: The `Look Up` works great, but I can't get the _toggle scroll lock_ to work. When holding the `Fn` key and pressing the `Lookup/ScrollLck` button results in a _right-click_. Is this what you're seeing as well, and curious if you have any tricks to enable the scroll lock?